# MS CRM 2013 - Get Selected Records of a Subgrid From a Button - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, subgrid

I added a button on my subgrid named "lots_associes", and I want by clicking on this button javascript recover all selected records.

I tried all the solutions proposed as http://vikramxrm.blogspot.fr/2013/11/read-subgrid-records-ms-crm-2013-using.html

But it seems that the functions "getElementById ('lots_associes')" do not work while "Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('lots_associes')" works. I have the good name of the grid.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In 2011, it was the Ribbon's job: I assume 2013 would be the same (despite the different look'n'feel).

You had to use `CrmParameter` to have the IDs of the selected records:

```
// in the RibbonDiffXml
<JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="YourFunc" Library="YourLibrary">
    <CrmParameter Name="MyRecordIDs" Value="SelectedControlSelectedItemIds" />
</JavaScriptFunction>

//The corresponding function would look like
function YourFunc(recordIDs){
    // recordIDS will be filled with the IDs of the selected records
}
```

[Here is the reference for CrmParameter (it says it applies to 2011 but there is no equivalent for 2013 so I believe this info is still valid)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309332.aspx)

On a side note, never use `getElementById` (it's not supported: no support from microsoft *and* any rollup might break your code).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this solution return all the records contain in the subgrid.

My problem now is that I only want those selected manually.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: I mis-copy-pasted the Value, now it's fixed. I also forgot to include the URL for the link... fixed that too.